# setCurrentItem for viewPager in nested fragment from recylerviewAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a parent activity (NavigationActivity) that has a viewPager with four fragments(frag1, frag2, frag3, frag4).

Then frag2 has a nestedViewPager with 3 fragments(nestedFrag1, nestedFrag2, nestedFrag3).

The nestedFrag1 has a recylerview that loads cards with images, and the images have an onCLickListerner.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    Poi_MDL poi = poiItems.get(i);

    viewHolder.poiTitle.setText(poi.getTitle());
    viewHolder.numComments.setText("" + poi.getNumComments());
    viewHolder.numLikes.setText("" + poi.getNumLikes());

    ArrayList<String> images = poi.getPhotos();

    if( images.get(0) != null){
        Log.d("IMAGE URL", images.get(0));
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(Constants.HOSTED_IMG_URL + images.get(0))
                .into(viewHolder.poiImg);
    }

    viewHolder.poiImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // This is where I want to call setCurrentItem for the nestedViewPager
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"" + context.getClass());

            Snackbar.make(v, "" + viewHolder.getAdapterPosition() , Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

When an image is clicked, I want to call setCurrentItem on the nestedViewPage.

How can I achieve this from the the recyclerview adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to solve this using the following method:

- In my nested fragment that has the recyclerView (nestedFrag2) I called getParentFragment() and instantiated it as a nestedFrag1 (that holds the viewPager)

  - I then set up an interface in my recylerView adapter and implemented the interface in nestedFrag2 and used the callback in the onBindView listener show above.

Answer (score 1):

I think it really depends on what your app is and what responsabilities your classes have...

I might implement an interface like ImageClickResolver on frag2 with a changePageForImage method then send this reference to newstedViewPager->nestedFrag1->adapter. So adapter has someone to call that is able to decide according to the image. Or just use Otto or an event bus so you emits an event when the image was posted and have frag2 listen to it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am exploring the following two solutions:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments